# Python install / Mac / Homebrew Python VSCode version

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, homebrew

I did a mess while installing python on Macos High Sierra by doing the same procedure on admin and user accounts. I used:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

and (only from the user account)

```
su admin
```

prior to the above code to do the same procedure because I was able to directly install from user before this. Then I got rid of Python 3 and homebrew on my admin account - and still have Python 2.7 there.

However, inside VSCode (in user account), I have a selection of two Python 3.8.3 versions:

```
Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

and

```
usr/local/bin/python3
```

admin account name: admin
user account name: Castor/Egon (folder name)

Should I delete one version, or otherwise, which version should I choose for smooth work in my user account?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/plzs5k6nbx4u9ci/Screenshot%202020-06-04%2010.31.30.png?dl=0 if my explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good way to get rid of remaining pytons. https://medium.com/faun/the-right-way-to-set-up-python-on-your-mac-e923ffe8cf8e

I removed all versions using `su admin` in the terminal to get bash.
Then I was able to execute the removal of all unnecessary python versions. 
The one needed for OSX is usr/bin/... whereas the additional versions are in usr/local/bin/... and other paths. After this, you can clean install brew again.